# cocos2d V3 sender in CCActionCallBlock

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, sender

As in cocos2d V2 before, I want to know the sender in a CCActionCallBlock.

```
id callFunc = [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishSeq:)]; //V2 style
id sequence = [CCSequnece actions: move, callFunc, nil];
[ship runAction:squence];

-(void) finishSeq: (id) sender {
          CCSprite* sprite = (CCSprite*) sender;
          sprite.opacity = 150;
}
```

Now in cocos2d V3 I have to use a block and I replace the callFunc:

```
id callFunc = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
      //how do I know the sender to change it's opacity ??
 }]
```

In this case I know it is "ship", but I want to use the sequence for different  objects.

Comment: since you'll issue a runAction on the intended node you have that node in scope, therefore your block can use it. Ie in a for loop where you get nodes from an array to run an action with call block, the currently enumerated node is the one you need to use in the block. The block "remembers" which node instance it was created with when enumerating.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the code that used to be on your `finishSeq:` method to the block, like this:

```
id callFunc = [CCActionCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
      ship.opacity = 150;
}];

id sequence = [CCSequnece actions: move, callFunc, nil];

[ship runAction:sequence];
```